Google Apps Script で変数の宣言位置の確認
ループ内で使用する変数の宣言位置について、以下のようにStrの宣言はループ内で行ってもいいのでしょうか？
const Values = ****省略
For(let i=0;i<Values.length;i++){
 let Str = Values(i);
 *** 以下省略
}

当初、let は再宣言できないので、ループ内ではＮＧ（エラーになる）と思ってました。
ループするたびに宣言するわけですからこれにひっかかると・・
なので宣言自体はループの外（前）で行っていました。
しかしやってみると問題なく動作しています。
変数にループのたびに加算されるものはループ内宣言はＮＧだとは思いますが、そうでない場合、これって良いのでしょうか？
可読性向上の為、1行でも減らしたいものです。

「再宣言」の捉え方が間違ってる気がします。/ 「変数にループのたびに加算されるものはループ内宣言はＮＧだとは思いますが」の意味がよくわかりません。サンプルコードなどあれば, そういったもので示されてると伝わりやすいかも

回答ありがとうございます
let Num = Num+1　のようなものが
ループ内にあると　
その出力はずーっと１のままになると思います

let Num = Num+1のような？ のは宣言として間違っているのでエラー(未定義の Numを使用しているため) です。

過去の投稿もそうですが、できれば句読点を省略せずに適切に使って欲しいです。

「再宣言」は, 下記 let v = 20の様な行を言います

ループ内のブロックは, 異なるブロックなので「再宣言」には当たりません

ただしその次の let v = 110 は「再宣言」でありエラー

(letではなく, var を使えば再宣言可能だが, デメリットが多いため利用しないほうがよいでしょう)

letと constの違いは「再代入」可能かどうかだが, 以下のような使い方なら constが望ましいかもしれない

(再代入は v = 20 などのように行う)


let v = 10
let v = 20   // SyntaxError: Identifier 'v' has already been declared at eval (<anonymous>)

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    let v = 100
    let v = 110   // SyntaxError: Identifier 'v' has already been declared at eval (<anonymous>)

    console.log(v +i)
}


そうでない場合、これって良いのでしょうか？

悪い記述ではないと思います

内容理解しました、ありがとうございます。
let, const, var の違い、スコープは理解してます。
